# Sync Framework - Delete not working after adding FilterClause

Tags: synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

After adding FilterClause, delete is not working anymore.

JuneT said [filter on tracking table which is Users_tracking](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/syncdevdiscussions/thread/e9e65166-d49c-47be-a8b3-61d12ac779b8)

However, I do not see IsPublished column in Users_tracking; I only see UserId.

Thank you for your help!

```
private static void ProvisionLocal(
   SqlConnection sqlLocalConn, DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc)
{
   var Users = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder
     .GetDescriptionForTable("Users", sqlLocalConn);

   scopeDesc.Tables.Add(Users);

   var sqlLocalProv = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(sqlLocalConn, scopeDesc);
   sqlLocalProv.CommandTimeout = 3600;

   sqlLocalProv.Tables["Users"].AddFilterColumn("IsPublished");
   sqlLocalProv.Tables["Users"].FilterClause = 
      string.Format("[side].[IsPublished] = {0}", 1);

   if (!sqlLocalProv.ScopeExists("TestScope"))
   {
     sqlLocalProv.Apply();
   }
}

private static void ProvisionRemote( 
   SqlConnection sqlRemoteConn, DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc)
{
   var sqlRemoteProv = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(sqlRemoteConn, scopeDesc);
   sqlRemoteProv.CommandTimeout = 3600;

   if (!sqlRemoteProv.ScopeExists("TestScope"))
   {
     // Apply the scope provisioning.
     sqlRemoteProv.Apply();
   }
}

public void Synchronize()
{    
   var sqlSourceConn = new SqlConnection("...");
   var sqlDestinationConn = new SqlConnection("...");

   var scopeDesc = new DbSyncScopeDescription("TestScope");

   ProvisionLocal(type, sqlSourceConn, scopeDesc);
   ProvisionRemote(type, sqlDestinationConn, scopeDesc);

   // Prepare for synchronization
   var localProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("TestScope", sqlSourceConn);

   var remoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("TestScope", sqlDestinationConn);
   remoteProvider.ApplyChangeFailed += RemoteProvider_ApplyChangeFailed;

   var orch = new SyncOrchestrator();
   orch.RemoteProvider = remoteProvider;
   orch.LocalProvider = localProvider;
   orch.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.Upload;

   SyncOperationStatistics stats = orch.Synchronize();

   sqlDestinationConn.Close();
   sqlSourceConn.Close();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the IsPublished column is at the bottom of your tracking table...

is your table part of another scope? are you adding another scope?

Comment: again, do you have an existing scope already on the destination? or are you starting with no scopes on both databases?

Comment: I only have one scope in both source and destination which is named 'TestScope'.

Comment: perhaps, i should rephrase my question. when you execute the code you posted above, do you have existing scopes in your database already? before you re-run your code above, can you try deprovisioning teh database first to get rid of all sync framework objects first.

Comment: Both are test databases. I deprovision both databases, and run the above code.

Comment: the filter configuration is added at the sqlLocalProv not to scopeDesc...so the second provisioning will not pick it up

Comment: Could you please suggest what I should change or fix since I'm new to SF?

Comment: just copy the filter clause code you setup to the provisioning of the remote provider and you should be good